# Regardless of user input my output is always the first item in my array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code should respond with the item in the array based on the integer the user put in, regardless of user input the response is always the first item in the array. I'm on week 3 of class so sorry if this isn't very well articulated. My code is:

````
// business logic

var responseSet = [[1, 'Beep!'], [2, 'Boop!'],[3, "won't you be my neighbor?"]];

var numChecker = function(number) {
  if (number === parseInt(number)) {
    return true; 
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var response = function(number) {
  for (var i =0; i < responseSet.length; i++) {
    if (number = responseSet[i][0]) {
      console.log(number)
    return responseSet[i][1];
    } else {
      return number;
    }
  }
}



//UI logic
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#converter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var userInput = parseInt($("#number").val());

    if (numChecker(userInput) === true){
      result = response(userInput)
    } else {
      result = "Beep, boop, This isn't a number try again"
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Typo -> `if (number = responseSet[i][0])`

Comment: To start, there _is_ a typo, but it is the use of a single `=` in your test in the _response_ function `if (number = responseSet[i][0])` — this _**assigns**_ to number, changing what the user entered. You'll need to use `==` or `===` there.

Comment: Close-Voters: the typo of `=` instead of `===` is not the _only_ problem. This is **not** "caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced."

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
if (number = responseSet[i][0]) {
```

You are setting the value of the variable (which is a truthy value) instead of doing a comparison, the correct result should be :

```
if (number == responseSet[i][0]) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, still learning some of the simpler stuff

Comment: ... As the comments (including mine) said. — but that's not the only problem, it _still_ isn't going to work with that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems; first is using `=` in the test in the *response* function. This *assigns* the value of `responseSet[i][0]` to number, changing what the user entered. Instead you want to *compare*:

```
if (number = responseSet[i][0])
```

should be

```
if (number === responseSet[i][0])
```

Then, again in the *response* function, you loop, but you always return from the loop on the *first* iteration.

```
var response = function(number) {
  for (var i =0; i < responseSet.length; i++) {
    if (number === responseSet[i][0]) {    // IF the number matches, return
      console.log(number)
      return responseSet[i][1];
    } else {
      return number;        // ELSE return anyway
    }
  }
}
```

You only want to return *number* if you've tested every item in `responseSet` so eliminate the *else* and move the return to be ***after*** the loop:

```
var response = function(number) {
  for (var i =0; i < responseSet.length; i++) {
    if (number === responseSet[i][0]) {    // IF the number matches, return
      console.log(number)
      return responseSet[i][1];
    }
  }
  return number;
}
```

Here's a stack-snippet that demonstrates it, shows what it's doing in the console, and puts the result in the page:

```js
var responseSet = [[1, 'Beep!'], [2, 'Boop!'],[3, "won't you be my neighbor?"]];

var numChecker = function(number) {
    if (number === parseInt(number)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var response = function(number) {
    for (let i=0; i<responseSet.length; i++) {
        console.log(`testing responseSet #${i} which is ${responseSet[i]}`);
        if (number === responseSet[i][0]) {
            console.log(`got number ${number}, returning object`);
            return responseSet[i][1];
        }
    }
    return number;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#converter").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const userInput = parseInt($("#number").val());

        let result =
            numChecker(userInput) ? response(userInput)
            : "Beep, boop, This isn't a number try again"
        console.log(`result is: ${result}`);
        $('#result').text(result);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="converter">
    <label for="number">Enter number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="results">
    The result is: <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```